Composing a message with mu4e doesn't add the To/From and other required fields
I get an error
message-position-on-field: Search failed: "^--text follows this line--
and the message itself does not have the required fields that should be added through message-mode.
I use the latest version of mu4e.

https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/2694
